# Spark-cluster vs Spark-client

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I feel that my question is related to the architecture of Spark. An application (developed in Java) is runnable on Yarn using yarn-client mode. The command is

`./bin/spark-submit --verbose --class path.to.Class --master yarn-client --files lib.so --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://master:8020/spark/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar --num-executors 30 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 3 myJarFile.jar`

But, if I change the mode into "yarn-cluster", I receive this error.

> *Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1440071752950_0001 finished with failed status
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:841)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:867)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)*

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to create the Spark context? Can you update  your question with an extended log of your exception?

Comment: I ve had the same problem. Does your application expect any file? like a configuration file or any other resource file??

Comment: Yes, there is a file that is needed for runs

Comment: and how is it visible on your  `spark-submit` command that you provided? it would help  determining the problem :)

Comment: Can you check logs from resource manager UI?

Answer (score 4):

In the command you provided you are missing the --jars option.

To quote the spark docu: "The --jars option allows the SparkContext.addJar function to work if you are using it with local files and running in yarn-cluster mode."

Answer (score 2):

Yarn client is driver on your gateway machine (from where you submit job). It will ask for executors only. But if you want to run kind of HA then you run yarn-cluster. In cluster mode , driver can go any node and in that way yarn will take care.

In above example you are missing some parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should crosscheck the command for running spark job in **yarn cluster mode**. 
you can refer [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check 3 main things here.

1. Check if you are creating the spark context inside the main method. I.e inside the driver. I have seen people creating it outside main       thinking it will be considered as global variable.
2. You don't have to refer the assembly jar. It will be invoked automatically. Check if you are missing any other jars that are used     in your application.
3. In client mode the driver will be running in one machine and executors will share cluster resources. In one of your answers I saw u mentioned that u r using a flat file. Please check if that file is in common directory in cluster. And in the program make sure you r accessing that file from HDFS instead of SC.textFile("file://...")

Answer (score 0):

You only can use client mode when you are sending spark submit from a worker machine, otherwhise you should use cluster mode to send it.

Answer (score -1):

In yarn client mode is when the driver program runs outside the yarn cluster .
In yarn cluster mode the driver program runs in app master .